# Does a SELECT with a JOIN lock a table like UPDATE does?

Tags: mysql, sql

If you were to SELECT and JOIN a large table that takes 10 minutes, would the table be locked so that data cannot be written to it?

From what I understand, there can be reads from the table while the SELECT JOIN is executing, how about UPDATEs or INSERTs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With InnoDB `SELECT` reads a snapshot created at the point in time that it's executed. Subsequent changes won't be visible. This isolation is the 'I' in 'ACID'

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) says this:

> A consistent read means that InnoDB uses multi-versioning to present
> to a query a snapshot of the database at a point in time. The query
> sees the changes made by transactions that committed before that point
> of time, and no changes made by later or uncommitted transactions.

The level of isolation can be controlled with various parameters. More details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)